# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.widget.ListPopupWindow

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, popupwindow

I want to display `ListPopupActivity` on a button click but it is throwing this exception.

I have read thoroughly about this exception but couldn't solve the problem
There is no jar file used in the project.

Here is the class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String[] listItems = {"item 1", "item 2 ", "list", "android", "item 3", "foobar", "bar", };
    Button btn;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  ListPopupWindow lpw = new ListPopupWindow(MainActivity.this);
                 lpw.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems));
                    lpw.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.btn));
                    lpw.setWidth(150);
                    lpw.setHeight(300);
                    lpw.show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Are you testing this in a device? Whats the api level of your device?

Comment: thats the problem. ListPopupWindow is api level 11. It wont work in this device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class [ListPopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html) was added in api level 11 (os version 3.0). I think you have set the targetSdkVersion to 11 in your manifest and trying to run your project in device that runs below api level 11.

Comment: Yes my device has OS version 2.3.5, so there is no backward compatibility for this class? can't i use this application on my device?

Comment: No my friend. You have to check for the api version at runtime and do some alternative if the api level is less than 11.

Comment: Well, there are backward compatibility support libraries for action bars, navigation menus, fragments and such now. Check out the android published v4 and v7 support libraries.